# How to force removing the section name in top of my pdf render

Tags: sectioning

How can I remove the name of each section title that appears on the top of my pdf document (between my 2 images) please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lastpage} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

%HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{images/im1.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{images/im2.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Workshop2, 2022-2023}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document} 
\section{Question 1 } 
\section{Question 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are adding the section name to the page head: `\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }`

Comment: Thanks so much it works! maybe you can right it as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the section name to the page head:

```
 \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
```

so simply delete this line.